# method drawBitmap change behavior since last samsung update?

Tags: canvas, bitmap, margins, drawbitmap

I have an application on Google Play published 4 or 5 months ago. The images had shown fine until the last samsung update.

In one part of the code I'm using the following function:

```
void android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)
```

The problem is that since the update does not behave as before about the margins when the `src` parameter are smaller than `dst`.

### Before

[BEFORE http://www.pegastacus.com/img/others/before_margins_ok.png](http://www.pegastacus.com/img/others/before_margins_ok.png)

### After

[AFTER http://www.pegastacus.com/img/others/after_margins_bad.png](http://www.pegastacus.com/img/others/after_margins_bad.png)

The value of the params are:

```
bitmap = A scaled bitmap from BitmapFactory.decodeResource of 328x222 px.

src = [-76, -289, 404, 511]

dst = the entire screen [0,0,480,800]
```

As you see, the margins should be 76px for left and right and 289px for top and bottom.

Why this suddenly change of behavior? I am lost. Anyone have any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Well,

The solution for me has been to change the function drawBitmap for this one

void android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint);

more simple and, with appropriate parameters, I get the same result as above.

Apparently there is no problem with the margins and the image is drawn as it should.